# Is there a query using SQLite to count valid unique email address from 3 separate email address field To, CC, BCC?

Tags: sql, regex

I have the following query I'm working with which results 1 per row but I know there is more than one email address stored within the field separated by semicolon

```
SELECT UID, EmailToField,
EmailToField REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' AS valid_emailTo
FROM table
```

For example my DB have

| UID | EmailTo | EmailCC | EmailBCC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | emailTo_1@domain.com; emailTo_2@domain.com | emailCC_1@domain.com | EmailBcc1@domain.com |

Expecting results to show

| UID | validEmailToCcBcc_count |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 4 |

Comment: That regex does not match emails, possible emails can be much broader. Instead, use a true email regex. Many programming languages have a library which makes one available. You can [create a SQLite function from that validator](https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-create-or-redefine-sqlite-functions/).

Answer (score -1):

Used AWK instead of SQL to obtain results, the following worked!

```
awk '{print NR " " gsub(/[a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/, "")}' test.csv > results.csv
```